# print string many times using eval function

Tags: python, eval

I used `for loop` but I could not figure out other ways.

```
name = input("Enter Your Name")

for i in range(10):
    print('String',end='')
print(name)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can try `print("String"*10)`

Comment: How does this relate to eval?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't use eval. Why do you want to?

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to use eval() you can do something like this:

```py
eval("print('String' * 10)")
```

Which is obviously just

```py
print('String' * 10)
```

I think you might be confused about the behavior of the eval function, the only thing it does is enable a Python script to execute a Python expression.

More info here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval